# UE4 C++ Access violation on class variable and unable to read memory on watchpoint

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, access-violation

I've been struggling with this problem for hours and I've looked and can't find the answer so sorry if it's been resolved elsewhere. I can't find an answer that matches. I'm alone and need help. I allocated a pointer in my class in BeginPlay. I reference it on every tick and it's fine. Then, when I call another event/function (UpdateCompassPointer) it blows up on the IF test to see if it's null or not with a read access violation! The watchpoint says `<Unable to read memory>`. All I can figure is that I've stepped all over my class but I don't see it. Here's my definition and then the code. The variable is HUDWidget. It's as fine as frog's hair on the tick, though!!!! Thanks for any help!
Update: I put another variable at the top of my cpp module to hold the same pointer and am using that for that one function and it's working fine. The Tick function continues to run with no problem but the other function blows up on any reference to that variable if I use it.  AMAZING!!

```
private:
    /** Crosshair asset pointer */
    class UTexture2D* CrosshairTex;
    UHUDWidget* HUDWidget;

void  ATheLostMine2HUD::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    if (HUDWidgetClass)
    {
        HUDWidget = CreateWidget<UHUDWidget>(GetWorld(), HUDWidgetClass);

        /** Make sure widget was created */
        if (HUDWidget)
        {
            /** Add it to the viewport */
            HUDWidget->AddToViewport();
        }
    }
}

void ATheLostMine2HUD::Tick(float DeltaSeconds)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaSeconds);
    if (HUDWidget)
    {
        if (GEngine)
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, FString::Printf(TEXT("Have HUDWidget")));

    }
}

void ATheLostMine2HUD::UpdateCompassPointer(float Yaw, float Degrees, float Direction, float Quad)
{
    if (HUDWidget)
    {
        HUDWidget->UpdateCompassPointer(Yaw, Degrees, Direction, Quad);
    }
    else
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("HUDWidget is not instantiated"));
}
```

More info and a question. Thanks for the nice comments, everybody! So I know I'm setting HUDWidget correctly because it works fine if I put it in my code. So, somehow, it's losing the value over in the header and the debugger is stopping on the If instead of the statement that caused it (as Ruzihm suggested). I'll put the UPROPERTY in as suggested and see what that does. Why would it get stale? I have another game with this exact same code (almost) and it works with no problems... I'll report back after the UPROPERTY update but I'm getting used to it being at the top of my code...
Curiouser and curiouser... the UPROPERTY didn't help anything.  So, in the Tick code I inserted a call using the HUDWidget pointer so it would crap out instead of the other function. It's still doing the same thing. The Tick code works and the other one bytes the dust!! I don't have a clue!!  Yeah, I figured it wasn't going to be something obvious. I don't need help with it. I can cut it down and build it back up myself and figure it out if I feel like it. It's a strange one, though. I appreciate the effort and offer, though! Thanks!

Comment: If the problem is with `if (HUDWidget)`, you're using an invalid `ATheLostMine2HUD` object. Trace your steps backwards to where it came from.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a MRE. It's possible you don't actually have HUDWidget in Tick, and that you only have a stale pointer, because it's only checking if the value of HUDWidget is not `nullptr`.  Try using the `UPROPERTY()` macro before `UHUDWidget* HUDWidget;` so the engine knows to set the pointer to null when/if the hudwidget gets destroyed. Also, I'm guessing that it *isn't* `if(HUDWidget)` that breaks, despite the appearance otherwise, but the `HUDWidget->UpdateCompassPointer(...);` that breaks. A [mre] would clear that up however.

Comment: Another possibility is that you aren't checking if your instance of `ATheLostMine2HUD` is valid before you call its `UpdateCompassPointer`. Doing `if (HUDptr) HUDptr->UpdateCompassPointer(...);` isn't enough to cover all cases, you should rather do `if (IsValid(HUDptr)) HUDptr->UpdateCompassPointer(...);`

Comment: I think we'll need to see more information about the situation to give any helpful answer. Please edit the question to include a [mre] so we have enough information to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unreal Engine implements its own Garbage Collection for UObjects.

You must markup your UObject derived pointers with `UPROPERTY` to ensure that the Unreal Reflection system can reference count the pointer to your UObject so that the Garbage Collection system doesnt destroy it out from under you when it runs.

```
UPROPERTY()
UHUDWidget* HUDWidget;
```

This should ensure that your HUD will remain alive while your still using it. As soon as all references to it are gone, the GC will take care of the Object for you and destroy it as necessary. If you dont do this markup as explained earlier, it will disappear without warning.

Comment: I did that and it did nothing.. I understand what you're saying and I've done that. Remember the Tick that references it too. The Tick keeps referencing without problem but the other function crashes. It makes no sense. Actually, on the first call to that function, it crashes. I'm tired of fighting it,to tell the truth.

Comment: It would help if you actually posted the actual Crash Log instead of paraphrasing it.